# YARN not using all memory available in a Google Dataproc instance

Tags: out-of-memory, google-cloud-platform, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running a Dataproc job using `h1-highmem-16` machines which have 104 GB of memory each.

I double-checked the size of the instances in the Google Console and all workers and the master are indeed `h1-highmem-16`.

Nevertheless, I get this error:

```
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 56.8 GB of 54 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

Why is YARN not using all 104 GB of memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dataproc configures memory settings to fit 2 Spark executors per machine, so each container should be expected to be half the capacity of each NodeManager.

You can optionally override `spark.executor.memory` and maybe `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` along with `spark.executor.cores` to change how you want to pack executors onto each machine. `spark.executor.cores` will default to half the machine's cores, since half the machine's memory is given to each executor. In your case this means each Spark executor tries to run 8 tasks in parallel in the same process.

You can effectively increase memory-per-task by reducing executor cores but keeping everything else the same, for example `spark.executor.cores=6` will increase per-task memory by 33% even if you leave everything else the same. These can be specified at job-submission time:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --properties spark.executor.cores=6
```

Comment: Reducing the number of cores worked, thanks. I had tried changing the executor memory and the memory overhead without any success, it was always using a few gigabytes more than the limit.

Comment: @Dennis Huo-- could you please suggest on below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77756346/spark-jobs-were-not-able-to-get-the-resources

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits" exception even when there was physical memory available on high memory instances.

I had to add "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled=false" when creating the cluster

```
 gcloud beta dataproc clusters create highmem-cluster --properties="yarn:yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled=false" ...
```

Followed by which I was able to run the job with the following executor sizes on n1-highmem-16

```
spark.executor.cores=15,spark.executor.memory=70g
```