# spark jobs were not able to get the resources

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

we have a dataproc cluster with below set of configuration with master node as `n1-highmem-16` and `n1-highmem-08` each for two worker nodes.

```
Machine type    vcpu    memory
n1-highmem-16   16      104   
n1-highmem-08   08      52
```

We are running our spark ingestion job with below set of properties.

```
Properties
spark.submit.deployMode client
spark.executor.cores 5
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors 2
spark.executor.memory 4g
spark.driver.memory 4g
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold 104857600
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.executor.memoryOverhead 1g
spark.executor.instances 1
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions 200
```

All of sudden jobs started taking long time. They kept on waiting for resources (for about 3 hrs) and when they get, jobs eventually taking less time only (5min).

why the spark UI is showing less container running.

As per my limited understanding Containers will be equal to total number of vcores.

[image]

given above vcpu configuration and memory for worker and master node. what could be the best combination of spark properties?

```
Total Available vCPUs and Memory on Worker Nodes
2 * 8vCpus = 16 vCpus 
2 * 52GB Memory = 104GB Memory
```

1 worker node will have 8cpu and 52 GB of memory whereas on spark UI it is showing approx 185 GB each

also how does Maximum Allocation gets calculated and allocated to the spark UI.

```
Maximum Allocation <memory:40960, vCores:8>
```

below is my `spark-defaults.conf` on master node

```
# Configure Spark on YARN
spark.master=yarn
spark.submit.deployMode=client
spark.yarn.jars=local:/usr/lib/spark/jars/*

# Dynamic allocation on YARN
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1
spark.executor.instances=10000
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=10000
spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio=0.0

# This undoes setting hive.execution.engine to tez in hive-site.xml
# It is not used by Spark
spark.hadoop.hive.execution.engine=mr

spark.rpc.message.maxSize=512

# Adding namespace to extract app_name and app_id for spark metrics
spark.metrics.namespace=app_name:${spark.app.name}.app_id:${spark.app.id}

spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://mbnl-pipe-emob-transform-v1-m/user/spark/eventlog
spark.history.fs.logDirectory=hdfs://mbnl-pipe-emob-transform-v1-m/user/spark/eventlog

spark.yarn.historyServer.address=mbnl-pipe-emob-transform-v1-m:18080

# User-supplied properties.
#Wed Sep 20 12:11:20 UTC 2023
spark.port.maxRetries=1024
spark.sql.cbo.enabled=true
spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR
spark.executorEnv.OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1
spark.executor.instances=2
spark.executor.memory=18619m
spark.extraListeners=com.google.cloud.spark.performance.DataprocMetricsListener
spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval=1d
spark.driver.memory=26624m
spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge=7d
spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled=true
spark.executor.cores=2
spark.yarn.am.memory=640m
spark.driver.maxResultSize=13312m
```

Let me know if I need to provide some more information.

How this `Memory Total & Mem Avail` gets calculated which is shown in spark UI screen shot below.

Please also suggest if we have to correct our spark properties.

**Update:**
given with two worker node cluster configuration as shown below:

```
Machine type    vcpu    memory
n1-highmem-08   08      52
```

Also, currently master node yarn-site.xml is updated as:

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores 8
```

it should be 7

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb 190000
```

it should be like 48 GB * 1024 = 49152

So, 1 worker node with `7 cpu` and `48 gb` memory availabe ( leaving some vCPU & memory per Worker node for deamons & OS )

Based on above configuration. I am planning to have below spark properties

```
spark.executor.instances 2
spark.executor.cores=3
spark.executor.memory=14g
spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2g
```

And based on master node config what could be the ideal configuration for master node.

```
Machine type    vcpu    memory
n1-highmem-16   16      104 
spark.driver.core=?
spark.driver.memory=?
spark.driver.memoryOverhead=?
```

[image]

Comment: Seems the num of executor cores is non-proportionally high, spark.executor.cores 5 means you can run 3 executors on each worker. 3 * (4G+1G) = 15GB memory.

Comment: You can check YARN resource manager logs https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/logging#cluster_logs_in. Enabling driver logs to DEBUG might also help https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/logging#job_driver_logging_levels

Comment: @ Dagang Wei.. Thanks for your response.. how this mem available gets calculated based on  memory avaiable for n1-highmem-08 workers

Comment: Dataproc has a logic for calculating default Spark values at cluster level, but user-provided cluster-level and job-level values takes precedence. The major problem I see with the user-provided value is that the num of executor core is too high, which leads to waste of memory.

Comment: @Dagang Wei. Thanks for your response. I have added few more details here. Could you please also have a look